# Update a python package installed by sudo command

Tags: python, package, sudo

Is it possible to update a cloned python package which is installed by using the command `$ sudo python setup.py install` or `$ python setup.py install --user` ?

If it is possible, then how do I go about doing it?

Thank you in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: Does the use of `sudo` affect potential solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If it was installed as `root`, you need to be `root` to update it.

If you installed it with `--user`, you can (only) update it as yourself.

Even if it's a system package, nothing prevents you from installing a newer version which shadows the system package, though. Try `pip --user` or learn about virtual environments.